# node id of jstree checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I need to retrieve the id of the node when unchecked.
On form submit the below code returns all the id of the selected node

```
checkbox: {
                real_checkboxes: true,
                two_state: true,
                real_checkboxes_names: function (n) {
                    return [("check_" + (n[0].id)), n[0].id]
                }
            }
```

But for my need i need the id when the node is unchecked like

```
}).bind('uncheck_node.jstree',function(e,data){
            {     
                var a=$(e).attr('id');               
                alert(a);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.bind("change_state.jstree", function (e, data) {
    if (data.args[1] == true) {
        var a = $(data.rslt).attr('id');
        alert(a);
    }
})
```

Comment: also one follow up question. How can i recheck this particular node like in place of alert(a)??

Comment: @BJ.BJ: you can also upvote the answer if you find if useful. ;-)

Comment: @Radek: sorry can't upvote!! my reputation is still below 15. Sorry!!